# Append inside brackets, quotes, double quotes

Tags: command

Been using Vim for a few weeks now and I find myself constantly using `ci"` or `ci(` to change whats enclosed in `""` or `()`.  I do also find myself wanting to append inside of the brackets e.g.:

If I have:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
```

I want to be anywhere on that line and append  `&& lastName == "Castle"` to my condition inside the `()`. To end up with:

```
if (name == "Frank" & lastName == "Castle") {
```

OR I want to append  `Castle` to what's inside the `""`. To end up with:

```
if (name == "Frank Castle") {
```

Obviously `ai"` and `ai(` doesn't work, since it puts you in append/insert mode and you then just type `i"`...

Anyone know how to do that, or if it's possible?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a command that follows the `ci...` structure to do that. You can
add a remap to do it (see below), or use core vim commands `f` and `t` (and
their counterparts `F` and `T`) motions to get the cursor to where you want,
and then switch to insert mode (with `i` or `a`) to effect the change (see even
further below).

## Adding a remap to do it

Here's a mapping to do it:

```
nnoremap <LEADER>ci" ci"<C-r>"
```

The way it works: The `ctrl + r` + `"` pastes from the unnamed register once in
insert mode - and since the unnamed register will contain whatever was between
the double quotes it just pastes it back in and leaves you in insert mode to
append your string:

Showing how the map works, step by step:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
```

`ci"` (this leaves you in insert mode)

```
if (name == "") {
```

`ctrl+r` + `"` (this pastes the content back, and leaves you in insert mode)

```
if (name == "Frank") {
```

Typing your addition  `&& lastName == "Castle"`:

```
if (name == "Frank && lastName == "Castle") {
```

## Using core vim (i.e. without a remap)

Relevant stuff from the help:

```
f{char}    To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The
           cursor is placed on {char}... 

F{char}    To the [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the left.
           The cursor is placed on {char}...

t{char}    Till before [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the
           right.  The cursor is placed on the character left of
           {char}...
            
T{char}    Till after [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the
           left.  The cursor is placed on the character right of
           {char}...

;          Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times.

,          Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction
           [count] times.
```

In the following, the `^` shows where the cursor is.

#### First case

```
if (name == "Frank") {
     ^
```

Pressing `f)`:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
                   ^
```

Typing `i && lastName == "Castle"`:

```
if (name == "Frank" && lastName == "Castle") {
```

#### Second case

```
if (name == "Frank") {
  ^
```

Pressing `t)` or `f";` or `2f"`:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
                  ^
```

Typing `i Castle`:

```
if (name == "Frank Castle") {
                         ^
```

#### Going backwards with `F`

```
if (name == "Frank") {
                     ^
```

Pressing `F"`:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
                  ^
```

#### Going backwards with `T`

```
if (name == "Frank") {
                     ^
```

Pressing `T";` or `2T"`:

```
if (name == "Frank") {
             ^
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah I’ve been doing exactly that. Just thought that there may have been something since the whole `ci”` works super well from anywhere on the line. 

Maybe it’s time I do some form of key map or something to handle this hehe.

Comment: @Albert I figured out a mapping for it (updated answer)

Comment: Hi @mattb, this is great! I have tried it and will be using this going forward :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

To help someone else looking for this, below is my complete mapping.

Note: `^R` is entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> which turns it into `^R`.

```
nnoremap <LEADER>ci" ci"^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci' ci'^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci( ci(^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci) ci)^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci{ ci{^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci} ci}^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci[ ci[^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci] ci]^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci< ci<^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci> ci>^R"<space>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci` ci`^R"<space>
```

Cheers,

Comment: You should be able to use `<C-r>`